# Extend and include in file system

Tags: uml, use-case

In our Software we want that the user to open a project file with different number of items (similar as in a Visual Studio Project) and he should be able to extract and insert these items from external sources (from other project, for example). I know the user should open projects, save projects, extract and insert items but, in terms of UML Use Case Diagrams, I don't know how to represent the three last user cases:

- Either as extensions from the first one, that only exist after the first user story occurs.
- Or representing the user case Open Project as an included Use case from the other three.

In the picture I have the two Use Case Diagrams. Are they both good?

[image: Use case diagrams]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself: is Open Project a use case? What is the added value? I guess there is none at all. So if there is no added value, it is not a use case. And if it is no use case, you don't need a bubble.

Comment: This with the added value is a good point. In the UML specification it is hard to know how to identify a Use Case. Is there some list of characteristics on how to know if something is a Use Case or not?

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the tricky parts. I read Spence/Bittner which helped me understanding this central point in use case synthesis. I greatly recommend this book to anyone going into the use case matter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either one of your solutions is correct.

The diagram with the extends indicates that we we might save a project while opening a project, which seems odd to me.

The diagram on the right says the inverse, while saving a project we also open a project. Again that seems wrong to me.

From my viewpoint these use cases all need to be separate use cases without an extend or include relation between them. They all seem to be somewhat on the same level. I can imagine that each of the use cases could be triggered by a single menu option.

Comment: And how would you represent the dependency between these Use Cases? Imagine a system with two Use Cases: Use Case A and Use Case B. But the Use Case B can only be done after Use Case A is done.

Comment: You should never express those kind of dependencies between use case, but use pre- and posconditions instead. Your Use Case B does not depend on Use Case A, but only on the result of Use Case A. If there would be a Use Case C that would yield the same result then that would be fine for Use Case B as well. Think loose coupling.

Comment: And what do you think about the suggestion of Thomas Kilian? Should "Open File" be a Use Case which generate the precondition for the other ones (in this case, "A File is opened")?

Comment: That depends on the actual case, and the reason you are modelling it. I can imagine that you would want to model it as a use case yes. Use case modeling is never black or white, always different shades of grey.

Comment: @Fleve Well, what is your opinion about the added value of Open Project. You know your domain. Out of the blue this does not sound as if it delivers any value. YMMV